# Omitting trailing zeroes / using sigfigs with d3.format()

Tags: d3.js, plotly.js

I am using d3 indirectly via Plotly and need to pass down a formatting string for numbers on the axis.

I'm having a hard time getting the effect described in this PR to work. https://github.com/d3/d3-format/pull/57

The syntax described in the PR isn't in the documentation https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Formatting.md#d3_format

Basically - is there a way to get rid of these trailing zeroes? I need to properly display arbitrarily small numbers (e.g. 0.00123), so simple truncation won't work - I need a true sigfig method that omits trailing zeroes

```
format = ".5g"
f = d3.format(format);
f(0.00123)           ==> 0.0012300 ☹
f(40)                ==> 40.000  ☹
f(5180.159999999996) ==> 5180.2 
f(999999)            ==> 1.0000e+6
```

[image: trailing zeroes from d3.js]

Comment: For some cases there actually are ways to inject/use formatters from other versions of D3. Could you be a bit more specific about where and how you want to use the formatter, i.e. which layout option of Plotly are we talking about?

Comment: @altocumulus this is specifically for the tickformat property of Axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the flag ('~') in your format to remove the trailing zeroes. This seems to work...

```js
format = ".5~g"
f = d3.format(format)
console.log(f(0.00123))
console.log(f(40))
console.log(f(5180.159999999996))
console.log(f(999999))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The `~` option to trim insignificant zeros was introduced by module d3-format v1.3.0 which was included into the bundle with v5.0.0 and is, hence, a v5+ solution. The latest version of Plotly, on the other hand, still uses D3 v3.5.12 which is why this solution is not applicable to OP's problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @altocumulus this was the piece I was missing, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: So, I guess this isn't possible with Plotly at the moment is my takeaway (at least not with the formatting mini language string).